# Why does the last term cancel in the infinite series, shouldn't the last term remain so the half the sum is less than two

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$\frac{S}{2}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}\right) \ldots$

The pattern I see is everything but the one and the -1/5 cancel in the finite series.
How does everything but the 1 cancel in the infinite series?

Comment: That last term tends to zero. Even if you don't consider it "cancelled", it still doesn't add anything to or subtract anything from the final result.

Comment: When you study calculus, you will learn the concept of "limit".

Comment: You're absolutely right to worry about that last term!  It's wrong to say that everything cancels except the $1$; instead, everything cancels except for $1$ and $-1/n$.  In this case, $-1/n\to0$, so it ends up not mattering; but in other examples, the last term doesn't go to $0$, and then you really do need it!

Answer (score 2):

If $$S_n = \sum_{i= 1}^n \left(\frac{1}{i} -\frac{1}{i+1}\right)$$ denotes the sum after adding $n$ terms (i.e. the last term is $\frac {1} {n} -  \frac {1} {n + 1}$), then $S_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ by the cancelation you noticed. If you let $n$ grow large, this is very close to $1$, so one says the infinite series, that is the limit of $S_n$ as $n$ tends to infinity, equals $1$.

Simply saying that the series equals 1 *''because every term except $1$ cancels eventually''* is not sufficient reasoning. The same could be said of the series $(1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1+ \dots)$, which does not converge.